# How to compare 2 European dates with JS?

Tags: javascript

Two European dates are given, e.g. "01.01.2016 10:00" and "03.01.2015 12:45". How can I compare them in JS?

```
      var valid_date      = new Date('01.01.2016 10:00');
      var execution_date  = new Date('01.01.2016 10:00');
```

Gives me an "Invalid Date" error.

Comment: you should have a look at [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). Javascript support for date formats is very thin on the ground

Comment: Globalize.js (https://github.com/jquery/globalize) is a good way to handle parsing of localized (differently formatted) dates.

Comment: Check out moment.js http://momentjs.com/ here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: yes there is, parse it manually using string manipulation. Moment.js and date.js we're written to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var valid_date      = new Date(2016, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0);
  var execution_date  = new Date(2016, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. And if the date as shown above comes from an INPUT field, is there any way to format or split it like required?

Comment: You would have to use some sort of substring method to extract the year, date, month etc. then parse them as integers using the `parseInt()` method. You can then use those variables in the Date constructor. Although this would only be valid if the date strings will always be in the same format as you have above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax of the dateStrings you are passing into the Date constructor is incorrect.

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse for correct syntax.

If you need a date object, you may need to parse the strings you have yourself to determine the year, month, day, etc.